# Jquery Check Form Validation Button Spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

When I click the submit button in the form, even if there is an empty input, the spinner in the jquery code starts to work. How can I fix the spinner to not work if the inputs are empty?

```
        <form action="{{ route('upload-item') }}" class="setting_form" id="item_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  
                  <div id="display_message"></div>
                  
                  <div class="row"> 
    
      <div class="col-sm-6 mb-1" id="pricebox_left">
                    <!--<label class="font-weight-medium" for="unp-standard-price">{{ 
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">{{ $allsettings->site_currency }}</span></div>
                      <input type="text" id="regular_price" name="regular_price" class="form-control" data-bvalidator="digit,min[5],required">
                    </div>
              </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="btnFetch" ><i class="dwg-cloud-upload font-size-lg mr-2"></i>Submit</button>
<form>
```

Jquery:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
          $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
            
          $(this).html(
            `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Loading...`
          );
          
          $("#btnFetch").submit();
          $(this).prop("disabled", true);
          
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop with [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) that will check for empty inputs.
Just before the loop, you make a var and you set it to false.
If one or more inputs are found empty then it set the var checkInputs to true.
If the var checkInputs is set to true, the form wont be submit.

I commented my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
          $("#btnFetch").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser behavior by default
            
            var checkInputs = false; // set the cheching var to false by default
            
            // loop every input in your form
            $("#item_form input").each(function() {
              // if one input or more are empty, checkInputs will be set to true
              if ($(this).val() == '') {
                 checkInputs = true;
              }
            });
            
            // if checkInputs is still set to false then submit form
            if (checkInputs === false) {
              $(this).html(`<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Loading...`);
          
              $("#btnFetch").submit();
              $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="{{ route('upload-item') }}" class="setting_form" id="item_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  
                  <div id="display_message"></div>
                  
                  <div class="row"> 
    
      <div class="col-sm-6 mb-1" id="pricebox_left">
                    <label class="font-weight-medium" for="unp-standard-price">{{ 
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">{{ $allsettings->site_currency }}</span></div>
                      <input type="text" id="regular_price" name="regular_price" class="form-control" data-bvalidator="digit,min[5],required">
                    </div>
              </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="btnFetch" ><i class="dwg-cloud-upload font-size-lg mr-2"></i>Submit</button>
<form>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser behavior by default` why? You just prevented the form from triggering the submit on its action attr value. If you really want to preventDefault than you'll also need AJAX to send the data instead...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it was to show that my code works

Comment: This code working but not check input validator rules. How can i get it checked? @SKJ

Comment: @tartari i answered that question, if you have another, make another one.